# over several years after the first experiment

Tags: meaning-in-context, syntactic-analysis

> Now, over several years after the first experiment, more than one hundred similar studies have been conducted all over the world.

Which parsing of 'over several years after the first experiment' is right? and what is the appropriate meaning of 'over'? 'during' or 'more than'?

1) If the meaning of 'over' is 'during', then the structure will be as follows:
[over several years] [after the first experiment]
In this parsing, each preposition phrase is separate.

2) If the meaning of 'over' is 'more than', then the structure will be as follows:
[[over several years after][the first experiment]]
In this parsing, 'over several years' modifies 'after'.
According to "A comprehensive grammar of the English language", 'Before' and 'After' may be modified to indicate relative proximity of time by a range of modifiers, eg: just, right, a long time, many days, a year, etc.

Comment: I read (and rewrote) it like this: _Now, [over **the** several years] [**since** the first experiment], more than one hundred similar studies have been conducted all over the world._

Comment: *During*, not *more than*.

Comment: *over several* is not commonly used to mean *more than several*: perhaps because of the ambiguity you have pointed out. In fact we would generally say, 'many years', or 'seven or eight', or 'ten or twelve' years after. So the meaning is surely this: "Now, several years since the first experiment, more than a hundred . . . "

Comment: Read it as "in the course of," of course, we don't use *over* with *many*, *several*, *...*. What exactly would you think "more than several" would mean, if anything? HTH.

Comment: I thank you all.